# umbraco content integration into hot towel spa web app

Tags: model-view-controller, umbraco, hottowel

I have an old website that displays content from umbraco per page.  This is done by using a pageload to call a webservice and render umbraco html content to a literal control. i.e.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://111.111.111.111:8080/api/PageContentApi?id=1122");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                aboutText.Text = html;
            }
        }
```

How would I accomplish this same rendering but in a MVC way for a hot towel spa application.  How should this be structured per view when a single page application is designed to load most content at start?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have solved this already. But, I'm in a similar situation and used Umbraco Library's RenderTemplate function. I'm using Umbraco 6.1.3